# Textbooks for Learning website security as a web developer?

Tags: self-learning, security

I've realized the value of computer science textbooks. As a web developer, I want to learn about security from an application's perspective. Something like how to prevent site from XSS, CSRF, SQL injection, File Traversal Vulnerability. I want a textbook to learn it.

What I know?

- Fourouzan Network Security
- Stallings network security
- Kauffman series in network security

But the issue is that these books only briefly talk about these concepts, I want a little bit more detail. I don't want practical though. I want to understand how to hack briefly, but I want to understand how to secure web apps in detail.

Please rcommend me some books to learn it. Specially computer textbooks.

Answer (score 3):

While this may not class as "textbook" one of the best sources of instruction on securing web applications is the the Open Worldwide Application Security Project (OWASP)

The [OWASP Top Ten](https://owasp.org/Top10/) provides detail on the ten most common mistakes/vulnerabilities that appear in Web Applications, how to prevent them, likely scenarios and a host of references.

- A01 Broken Access Control
- A02 Cryptographic Failures
- A03 Injection
- A04 Insecure Design
- A05 Security Misconfiguration
- A06 Vulnerable and Outdated Components
- A07 Identification and Authentication Failures
- A08 Software and Data Integrity Failures
- A09 Security Logging and Monitoring Failures
- A10 Server Side Request Forgery (SSRF)

This will give you what you have asked for in your headline "how to learn website security" however it will not answer your different question further down your post "I want to understand how to hack." You will gain some perspective on that, but OWASP Top Ten is very much focused on defending and securing.

If you are interested in learning more, I would suggest visiting [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) as this is our bread and butter over there. We look at everything from web security to physical security, strategy to policy, red teaming to blue teaming etc.